# How can I raise an event with its original effect in WPF?

Tags: wpf, button, mouseevent, raiseevent

I know that I can use `RaiseEvent` to raise an event, like raise a MouseDownEvent on a button.

I use the mouse to click on a `Button`. It has a `MouseDown` effect (like background change to blue), but I use `RaiseEvent`. It just does the `MouseDown` function, not triggering the button's `MouseDown` effect.

How can I raise an event with its original effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you can't. That effect is bound to the [IsPressed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.ispressed.aspx) property of the Button. Like wise the [IsMouseOver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ismouseover.aspx) is used to determine if the mouse is hovering over the button. You can't really change/set these properties.

You could restyle the Button control to render these effects when one or more custom attached properties are set. But you can't induce the effect by raising events.